# How to exclude nights from a TSQL query?

Tags: t-sql, datetime

I'm writing a TSQL query to find the next available datetime from a list of appointments. So far what I've managed to get working does find the gaps in a time query but I can't seem to find a great way to exclude nights (after 7pm lets say).

```
;WITH CTE
AS (  SELECT 
         ID,StartAptDate,EndAptDate, 
         RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY StartAptDate ASC )
      FROM Appointments WHERE StylistId = 1 AND StartAptDate > CAST( CONVERT( CHAR(8), GetDate(), 112) AS DATETIME)
   )
   SELECT FirstApptAvail = min( a.EndAptDate )
   FROM CTE a
      INNER JOIN CTE b
         ON a.RowNumber = b.RowNumber - 1
   WHERE datediff( minute, a.EndAptDate, b.StartAptDate) >= 15 AND ...
```

A little pseudo code for the ... would be something like this

(a.StartAptDate < GETDATE **@7pm** AND a.StartAptDate > GETDATE + 1 **@8am**)

The part I can't seem to get right is constructing the right side of each comparison. I need to exclude anything that might be returned between 7pm that night - 8am the next morning.

Thank you in advance

Comment: can't you use WHERE ( [DATE VALUE] BETWEEN '07:00:00' AND '19:00:00' ) ?

Comment: excellent! It would appear I over-engineered this already :)

Comment: or you could do WHERE ( [DATETIME VALUE]::time >= '07:00:00' AND [DATETIME VALUE]::time <= '19:00:00' ), also, you should get the "time" of the date time value in order to have a good filter [DATETIME VALUE]::time

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the quick feedback - it looks like I was able to get the desired result using the BETWEEN statement mentioned in the comments above. I first made the startdate and enddate in question time specific (meaning the date part was 1900 / 01 / 01 so it didn't matter) This way I could use the time ONLY to compare with.

```
;WITH CTE
AS (  SELECT 
         ID,StartAptDate,EndAptDate, 
         RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY StartAptDate ASC )
      FROM Appointments WHERE StylistId = 1 AND StartAptDate > CAST( CONVERT( CHAR(8), GetDate() - 5, 112) AS DATETIME)
   )
   SELECT FirstApptAvail = min( a.EndAptDate )
   FROM CTE a
      INNER JOIN CTE b
         ON a.RowNumber = b.RowNumber - 1
   WHERE datediff( minute, a.EndAptDate, b.StartAptDate) >= 15 AND (CAST ( CONVERT( CHAR(8), a.StartAptDate, 108) AS DATETIME) BETWEEN '1900-01-01 07:59:59' AND '1900-01-01 18:59:59' AND CAST ( CONVERT( CHAR(8), a.EndAptDate, 108) AS DATETIME) BETWEEN '1900-01-01 07:59:59' AND '1900-01-01 18:59:59')
```